# Creating a new FTP user and giving him only the right to 1 folder

Tags: permissions, users, ftp, account-restrictions

I have a Linux Debian machine that I own (root access).

I would like to create a new user called "testuser" and give him the right to view, edit and delete files from only one specific folder located in

```
/var/www/html/specificfile
```

I do not mind if the user can see which other files exist in `/var/www/html/` (or anywhere else). But the user definitely can **only** view, edit and delete the files contained in the folder `/var/www/html/specificfile`.

The user ("testuser") isn't created yet.

How do I  perform this action?

The user will access the machine only over FTP.

Comment: Did you look at `chroot(8)` ?

Comment: FTP (The ftp server is already installed on the machine)

Comment: The FTP server itself should have a chroot option, that may suit your needs. If you use e.g. openssh's internal sftp, it has that functionality built-in, see ChrootDirectory option.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to allow FTP access only, right? Allowing FTP access only and allowing command line access would require very different configuration.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15360/how-to-add-a-ssh-user-who-only-has-permissions-to-access-specific-folder for SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hard link to the file...
Hard and Soft link reference: [The Ultimate Linux Soft and Hard Link Guide | The Geek Stuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/linux-ln-command-examples/)

You can approach this several different ways, here might be the two common ways:

1. Create a directory that the user has access to upon ftp login (users root ftp directory) and created the link there.
2. Create the link in the users home directory and link the file in the users home directory.